# Why do I get an error when I use THTTPClient.Post like THTTPClient.post(url,data,jsontoget)?

Tags: delphi, httpclient

When I use it like this, I get a response：

```
idhttp.Post(url,data,jsontoget,nil,heads);
```

but when I use it like this:

```
idhttp.Post(url,data,jsontoget);
```

I get an error:

> Project Project1.exe raised exception dass ENetHTTPClientException with message Error sending data: (87)parameter error

The code is as follows：

```
var
  url,str:string;
  JsonToSend,jsontoget: TStringStream;
  data:Tstrings;
  LHeaders: array of TNameValuePair; 
  IdHttp :THTTPClient;
begin
  url:='http://*******/getPsnByCondition';
  IdHttp:=THTTPClient.Create;
  idhttp.Accept:='application/json,text/plain,*/*';
  idhttp.AcceptCharSet:='utf-8'  ;
  idhttp.AcceptEncoding:='gzip,deflate';
  idhttp.AcceptLanguage:='zh-CN,zh;q=0.9';
  idhttp.ContentType:='application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
  idhttp.UserAgent:='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
    +'Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36';
  idhttp.CustomHeaders['Cookie'] :='XSRF-TOKEN='+edt2.Text+';SESSION='+edt1.Text;
  idhttp.CustomHeaders['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] :=edt2.Text;
  idhttp.CustomHeaders['Host'] :='******';
  idhttp.CustomHeaders['Connection']:='keep-alive';
  idhttp.CustomHeaders['Content-Length:']:='177';
  idhttp.CustomHeaders['Origin'] :='*****';
  idhttp.CustomHeaders['Referer'] :='http://******/N1412.html';

  data:=tstringlist.Create;
  data.Clear;
  data.Add('psnCertType=01');
  data.Add('certno=******');
  data.Add('searchInsuEmp=true');
  data.Add('menuQuryPerm=4');
  data.Add('_modulePartId_=');
  data.Add('fron_tUrl=http://********/N1412.html#/N141201');

  SetLength(heads, 8);
  heads[0] := TNameValuePair.Create('Cookie', 'XSRF-TOKEN='+edt2.Text+';SESSION='+edt1.Text);
  heads[1] := TNameValuePair.Create('X-XSRF-TOKEN', edt2.Text);
  heads[2] := TNameValuePair.Create('Host','*****');
  heads[3] := TNameValuePair.Create('Connection','keep-alive');
  heads[4] := TNameValuePair.Create('Content-Length','177');
  heads[5] := TNameValuePair.Create('Origin','*****');
  heads[6] := TNameValuePair.Create('Referer','******/mbs/ui/N1412.html');
  heads[7] := TNameValuePair.Create('Accept-Encoding','gzip,deflate');

  jsontoget:= TStringStream.Create('',TEncoding.UTF8);
  jsontoget.Position:=0;
```

When I debug it step by step, in `unit System.Net.HttpClient`:

```
...
procedure THTTPClient.ExecuteHTTPInternal(const ARequest: IHTTPRequest; const AContentStream: TStream; const AResponse: IHTTPResponse);
   ...
      LExecResult := DoExecuteRequest(LRequest, LResponse, AContentStream);
//this function can not goto next;
  ...
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug you should [report to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: I'm not sure.  And I don't have an account :(

Comment: Then create one